# Rake test loader - load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I am a new with ruby.

I am trying to run rake test from the application root and I get loaderror, no such file to load from the rake test loader : 5, i.e. it is not able to locate or load the test files.

I created a new app to see if this behaviour is app. related, but it still doesn't work.

Where should I look? Is this related to the PATH variable or ..? I would like to avoid reinstalling ruby.

Thanks,
gabi

Answer (score 0):

The [`rake` documentation](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) would be a good place to start.  You're probably missing a `Rakefile`.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. I looked over but still don't understand what it is missing. Can you give me another hint on where should I look in the rake doc?

Comment: There really isn't enough detail to answer.  At least, not enough for _me_ to answer.  Do you have a `Rakefile` in the directory from which you're running `rake`?  If not, I'm not sure what the answer is, but you may get a better one if you post the complete stack trace of the error, instead of the summary.

Answer (score 0):

if in the rake_test_loader.rb would know the full path of the test files beeing loaded it seems to work. But even so, I get an error - sqllite3 not found for monitor.rb - which is weird since I explicitly configured the project and the test env for mysql. Update .. after restarting it work .. but still. Probably something to to do with the load_path